# How can I set top margin of the first page of pdf document using iText7?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I want to set top margin of my first page. Unfortunately it doesn't work. I tried the `document.SetTopMargin(100)` but that sets all pages. I just want to set my first page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The margin for the next page has to be set before the page break.

```
document.SetTopMargin(100);
document.Add(new Paragraph("Text on first page"));
document.SetTopMargin(0);
document.Add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
document.Add(new Paragraph("Text on second page"));
```